# Want to use ResNet50 pretrained but got error "ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 7, 7, 3) are incompatible"

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, resnet

I want to try the `ResNet50` pretrained model but got this error, I don't know what happened and tried to change the shape but did not work.

Code:

```
for layers in (ResNetmodel.layers)[:19]:
print(layers)
layers.trainable = False
X= ResNetmodel.layers[-3].output
X=Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')(X)
X=Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu')(X)
predictions = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(X)
model_final = Model(inputs = ResNetmodel.input, outputs = predictions)
model_final.summary()
model_final.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer =  optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.6), metrics=["accuracy"])
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_"+a+".h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=40, verbose=1, mode='auto')
history=model_final.fit_generator(generator= traindata, steps_per_epoch= 2, epochs= 50, validation_data= testdata, validation_steps=1)
```

Error:

> ---> 23     history=model_final.fit_generator(generator= traindata, steps_per_epoch= 2, epochs= 50, 
>   validation_data= testdata, validation_steps=1)
>  24     model_final.save_weights("/content/gdrive/My Drive/cnn/modelvgg350tanpapooling- 
>   3sgd0000109"+a+".h5")
>  25     testdata1.reset()
>  ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 7, 7, 3) are incompatible

Comment: How are you creating ResNetmodel? what parameters are you passing?

Comment: ResNetmodel = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True) in this way

Comment: If you want to add your layers, you have to do include_top=False and then x = Dense(...)(resnet base)

Comment: no still dont work if set tu false this occur alueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, None, None, 3) are incompatible

Comment: My bad, you are supposed to use x=Dense(..)(ResnetModel.output) instead of layers. If you do include_top=False, you are not adding final dense layers for imagenet as you want to add your own, so you also dont have to do layers[-3]. The error seems like it happens during checkpoint, if you can create a small reproducible example, i or someone can try it as well (with some random generated data)

Comment: ive tried to change the dense not work, i tried tu disable checkpoint didnt work too, any ideas?

Comment: the eror occur inline 23 in history = model_fit

Comment: are these lines part of your code? `model_final.save_weights("/content/gdrive/My Drive/cnn/modelvgg350tanpapooling- 3sgd0000109"+a+".h5") 25 testdata1.reset()` I can help better if I can reproduce the error

Comment: yess that part is my code

Comment: hi, im bram thank you so much for you help i really appriciate it

Comment: try adding `x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(ResNetmodel.output)` and then Dense layer (`x = keras.layers.Dense(128)(x)`)

Comment: `import keras`
`import numpy as np`
`mod = keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False)`
`x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(mod.output)`
`x = keras.layers.Dense(128)(x)`
`model = keras.models.Model(mod.input, x)`
`model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())`
`model.fit(np.random.rand(10,200,200,3), np.random.rand(10,128,1))`

Comment: i tried ur suggest but didn work

Comment: Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: still error occur at model.fit, i change it to     history=model.fit(traindata, steps_per_epoch= 2, epochs= 50, validation_data= testdata)

Comment: You are not showing your code enough for me to help you, does the code that i posted work (without any of your code)? Because it works for me. If I cannot reproduce the error you get, I can't help.

Comment: can i post my screenshot and share the link to you? or should i add my code to ask section?

Comment: Edit your question with minimum reproducible code, ie, code which anyone can quickly run without extra requirements such as that of training data (create random numpy arrays of proper shape). Follow the instructions given here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)